# Can you add default documents within the documents folder for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdata

I am developing an App which will receive it's data from a remote XML file. I've created a way for checking if there's an update available with XML. This will compare to dates (one local and one remote). If the remote date is newer you can choose to fetch the new data. This data will be saved within the documents folder.

However, I would like to put some default information within the applications document folder. So, when people download the app, the default information is added to the documents folder.

Is this possible? If so, how? And if not, what's the best solution for this kind of operations?

With kind regards Douwe

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible to achieve this. Whatever default information you want to put in the application's document directory, you would have to include it in your app bundle (xcode project). Then, on app launch, you can check whether that information exists in the documents directory. If it doesn't, you can copy it there.

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: Okay, thanks Akshay for your quick response. So correct me if I am wrong, I have to place the (XML) files within my bundle so I can add them to the documentsfolder when the application starts. So I cannot place the files directly into the documentsfolder. Instead I check for existing files, if not exist, copy from bundle, and if remote update date is newer then the local one, I can check the information from the remote address? -thnx

Comment: How can you add files directly to the documents directory of all iDevices on which your app will execute without copying them programmatically? :-) You are correct with the rest of your comment. Please mark it as the answer if you liked it.

Comment: Means we cant keep default data in document folder. We have to copy data into document folder from app bundle?